# Having more than one bot admin in Telegram

Tags: bots, admin, telegram-bot

I administer a group on Telegram and have created some bots using Bot Father and Manybot.

Now, I have got someone who will help me create content and schedule the Posts. I can’t find out how to allow her to access the bot and have editing rights.

Is it possible?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(wrong, check the comment below) only thing you can do is to transfer your bot to "someone" with
@BotFather -> /mybots -> some_bot -> Transfer Ownership -> "someone"

Comment: Thanks Dann for helping! 

 I am using Manybot and was pointed in the right direction.  It’s possible.